# Вылетает ошибка json.loads Python 3.6

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, telegram-bot

Есть код:

```
import json

msg = '[{"update_id": 4444, "message": {"message_id": 44, "from": {"username": "USER007"}, "text": "Hello World"}}]'
req = json.loads(msg)
username = req['message']['from']['username']
```

Не получается извлечь данные из объекта json, в чем ошибка?

Comment: `req` это список, а не словарь

Comment: Ну  и где полный traceback исключения?

Comment: @andreymal а какая разница? Мне приходит ответ от телеграма в формате json, как данные вытащить?

Comment: @6NGY30E очень и очень большая, вы обращаетесь к нему как к словарю, скармливая ключ-строку, а надо обращаться как к списку, скармливая индекс-число. Вы знаете основы питона и понимаете разницу между словарём и списком? Если нет, то сперва прочитайте любой учебник по питону.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У Вас словарь в списке, либо так:

```
import json

msg = '[{"update_id": 4444, "message": {"message_id": 44, "from": {"username": "USER007"}, "text": "Hello World"}}]'
req = json.loads(msg)
username = req[0]['message']['from']['username']
```

Либо если в списке несколько словарей, можно пройтись в цикле:

```
for i in req:
    print(i['message']['from']['username'])
```